# julia intialize array unknown size

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, initialization, julia

In Julia programming language, I want to create an structure that holds an MxN matrix of zeros, but I can only know M and N when I initialize the structure. In Python it would be something like:

```
class MyStruct:
    def __init__(self, M, N):
        self.data = np.zeros(shape=(M,N))
```

Is that possible in Julia?

Comment: what about `zeros(m,n)`

Comment: But I need that inside a structure because there is other types of data that go along together, like indexes, etc...

Answer (score 5):

In Julia the type of an array is not affected by its size. Only dimension (matrix/vector etc).

Thus you can simply write

```
struct MyStruct{T}
     data :: Matrix{T}
end
function MyStruct(m,n) 
    MyStruct(zeroes(m,n))
end
```